# can I add the same DataTable with same name to a DataSet multiple times?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable, ado.net, dataset

i have 12 datatables in the list Like "A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D"
I want to add these datatables to dataset and then write to Xml but it shows the exception:'A DataTable named 'A' already belongs to this DataSet

```
    For Each dataTable In dtList
        dsxml.Tables.Add(dataTable.Copy())
    Next
    dsxml.WriteXml(path)
```

need help how to achieve this.

Comment: [DataTable.TableName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.tablename?view=netframework-4.8) can be changed

Comment: A dataset can not have more than one tables with same name in it. That's why you are getting this error. You should either use unique names of tables in the list or combine tables with same names and then add them to dataset

Comment: ChetanRanpariya - How to combine tables with same names?

Comment: Do the tables with the same name have the same schema?

Comment: jmcilhinney - tables name A,A,A  B,B,B  C,C,C  and D,D,D have same schema but record is different

Comment: Look into `DataTable.Merge` to combine identical schema into one `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding tablename to datatables  will solve the issue. I had created a small tested code snippet for your understanding..

```
''Sample class to hold datatables and their names
    Class cls_dtlist
        Public Property TableName As String
        Public Property Tabledata As DataTable
    End Class

    Sub Main()

        ''Dummy Tables
        Dim A As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim B As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim C As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim D As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim E As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim F As DataTable = New DataTable()


        Dim pathofXml As String = "your path"


        Dim dtlist As List(Of cls_dtlist) = New List(Of cls_dtlist)

        ''Adding datatables to class and then list
        dtlist.Add(New cls_dtlist With {.TableName = "A", .Tabledata = A})
        dtlist.Add(New cls_dtlist With {.TableName = "B", .Tabledata = B})
        dtlist.Add(New cls_dtlist With {.TableName = "C", .Tabledata = C})
        dtlist.Add(New cls_dtlist With {.TableName = "D", .Tabledata = D})
        dtlist.Add(New cls_dtlist With {.TableName = "E", .Tabledata = E})
        dtlist.Add(New cls_dtlist With {.TableName = "F", .Tabledata = F})


        Dim dsxml As DataSet = New DataSet()

        For Each dataTable In dtlist

            dataTable.TableName = dataTable.TableName

            dsxml.Tables.Add(dataTable.Tabledata.Copy())
        Next

        dsxml.WriteXml(pathofXml )

    End Sub
```